# Root segment cannot have matrix parameters Ionic 4

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

Any clue how to solve this?

*.ts*

```
this.navCtrl.navigateRoot(["", { hotelId: data.h }])
```

*route*

```
           {
                path: "",
                component: HomePage,
            },
```

> Unhandled Promise rejection: Root segment cannot have matrix
>   parameters ; Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Root
>   segment cannot have matrix parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me. i.e. `NavigationExtras`

*.ts*

```
import { NavigationExtras } from "@angular/router";

 const navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
          queryParams: { "hotelId": data.h },
        };    

this.navCtrl.navigateRoot([""], navigationExtras);
```

**Ref:** [Route Doc](https://angular.io/guide/router#query-parameters-and-fragments)